# keytool error: Certificate reply does not contain public key for

Tags: certificate

I've recently purchased a certificate from GoDaddy for coding signing an Adobe Air application.

I generated a CSR (Code Signing Request) file and sent it to them. They have send back a .spc certificate file (PKCS #7 format).

I'm using keytool that comes with Adobe Air. Here are the commands that I have used.

**Generate CSR:**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Flex Builder 3\jre\bin\keytool.exe" -genkey -alias codesigncert -keypass password123 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=displayname,O=companyname,C=US,ST=state,L=city" -keystore codesignstore
```

**Import certificate into keystore:**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Flex Builder 3\jre\bin\keytool.exe" -import -alias codesigncert -file cert.spc -keystore codesignstore
```

After running this command the error I get is:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Certificate reply does not contain public key for <codesigncert>
```

What could have gone wrong?

The guide that I am following is this one:
http://help.godaddy.com/article/4780

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was very simple. The certificate file was not generated by the CSR file, it was generated by a different CSR file. I simply got a new certificate and it worked.

Once the certificate as imported into the keystore, I could run the following command to sign the Adobe Air intermediate file.

```
adt -sign -alias codesigncert -storetype jks -keystore codesignstore -storepass storepass123 -keypass password123 "C:\myapp\widget.airi" "C:\myapp\widget.air"
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I created/imported my cert using the same CSR/CSR alias, into the same keystore(/hash) from which CSR was gen'd.  Still get this error.  It's a PKCS#7/cert chain, but should still work.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem; a mismatch between the issued certificate and the certificate request file resulted in the error message:

`keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Certificate reply does not contain public key for <xyzzy>`

In my case, I was using a different certification authority, Thawte.  The cause of the problem was that when I went to the Thawte certificate website to pick up my newly-issued certificate, the site said my certificate was ready to be downloaded, but curiously by default they had selected a different, two-year-old certificate, not the one which had just been issued.  So, I downloaded the wrong certificate.  It wasn't until I did:

`keytool -printcert -v -file the-pkcs7-file`

and saw the old dates on the certificate that I realized what had happened.  I then downloaded the correct PKCS7 certificate file.